# Phoenix default response content-type of "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8" for a json-api request

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, json-api

I'm writing a [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/) complaint api in my phoenix application using the library [ja_serializer](https://github.com/AgilionApps/ja_serializer). The request is only being routed through an :api pipeline which looks like:

```rb
pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json-api"]
    plug JaSerializer.ContentTypeNegotiation
  end
```

The controller/action is essentially:

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Api.DataController do
  use MyApp.web, :controller

  def show(conn, params) do
     query = # build a query
     render(conn, Repo.one query)
  end
end
```

The plug "JaSerializer.ContentTypeNegotiation" will write the correct `content-type` response header in a `before_send` hook only if a `content-type` response header hasn't already been set. For some reason the `content-type` header is being set to "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8" by some code in phoenix, or plug, or the accepts plug or something.

I don't want to have to write a plug that just slaps on the correct content type. What is causing this and How do I make sure the `content-type` header isn't set by the time the JaSerializer.ContentTypeNegotiation plug is called?

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller/action where the content-type is being set to `octet-stream`?

Comment: The plug responsible for setting this is the `mime` plug at https://github.com/elixir-lang/mime/blob/master/lib/mime.ex  - hope this helps your research.